# Facebook messenger file naming scheme

Tags: facebook, metadata, messenger

I'm currently in process of correctly tagging all of my saved images, including the ones from Facebook and messenger. Does anyone know if there is a way to extract the correct create date from the filename or at least some naming convention so I can do more searching? :)

Here are some examples of filenames:

[some examples of file names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlKdb.jpg)

Comment: Could you please add some example?

Comment: Just edited the post to add some examples